# To know line number while debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

How to know line number during debugging when source code contains several empty lines? For example I have code:

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, num, j;
    printf ("Enter the number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num );

    for (i=1; i<num; i++)
        j=j*i;    

    printf("The factorial of %d is %d\n",num,j);
}
```

line number 10 contains line `j=j*i;`

If I compile code below (with removed empty lines) `cc -g factorial.c` and add breakpoint in line 10 I still have line `j=j*i;`there. But this line now is in line number 8. Why it still stops in line `j=j*i;`?

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int i, num, j;
        printf ("Enter the number: ");
        scanf ("%d", &num );
        for (i=1; i<num; i++)
                j=j*i;
        printf("The factorial of %d is %d\n",num,j);
}
```

How to manage line numbers, when I write code in vim that shows line number in bottom right?

Comment: In this case you might be using old executable for debugging purpose, it might not be updated with new symbols. check executable last modified type it should be updated to new time after compilation.

Comment: I also have seen this behaviour when using different gcc versions for compiling and linking...

Comment: In vim to manage line number you can set number flag to show all hidden line number. check [this](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afcx) link

Comment: Not to answer your question, but there are at least two bugs in the program: `j` is never initialized, so the program computes garbage, and the loop termination condition is wrong (if `j` was to be initialized to 1).